# SelectManyCheckBox java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to javax.faces.model.SelectItem

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, icefaces

I have the following problem when i use the selectManyCheckBox:

campaignInformationForm.campaignInformation.googleAnalytics (this are boolean objects)

> java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to
>   javax.faces.model.SelectItem

and my code is:

```
<ice:selectManyCheckbox id="options" layout="pageDirection" >
        <f:selectItem itemValue="#{campaignInformationForm.campaignInformation.googleMerchantAccount}" itemLabel="#{msgs['page.information.GoogleAccount']}" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="#{campaignInformationForm.campaignInformation.googleMap}" itemLabel="#{msgs['page.information.GoogleMap']}" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="#{campaignInformationForm.campaignInformation.googleAnalytics}" itemLabel="#{msgs['page.information.GoogleAnalytics']}" />
    </ice:selectManyCheckbox>
```

Any ideas?

**Edit:**

This is my DTO

```
public class CampaignInformation implements Serializable{
.....BOILERPLAIT CODE    ...
        private boolean googleMerchantAccount;
    private boolean googleMap;
    private boolean googleAnalytics;
.....GETTER/SETTER   ...
```

And i want a checkbox that can work with those boolean select/deselect according to their value, can it be done??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The f:selectItem tags in your example here are correct. I'm almost sure you used "value" instead of "itemValue" in one selectItem (perhaps you deleted one for a clean example?).

Also, where will the selection be stored? I guess you should have a "value" property (really, this time) in ice:selectManyCheckbox, like this:

```
<ice:selectManyCheckbox id="options" layout="pageDirection" value="#{campaignInformationForm.selectedItems}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{campaignInformationForm.campaignInformation.googleMerchantAccount}" itemLabel="#{msgs['page.information.GoogleAccount']}" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{campaignInformationForm.campaignInformation.googleMap}" itemLabel="#{msgs['page.information.GoogleMap']}" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{campaignInformationForm.campaignInformation.googleAnalytics}" itemLabel="#{msgs['page.information.GoogleAnalytics']}" />
</ice:selectManyCheckbox>
```

(selectedItems being a List or array of selected items)

Comment: what i want to do is set #{campaignInformationForm.campaignInformation.googleMerchantAccount} the value of the selected... for example if is selected this will be true and you are right i used value but now i am lost how can i bind  it with the component

Comment: I just edited my answer. The list of selected values is specified by the selectManyCheckBox tag.